# How to display different data if a switch is toggled in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a donut chart that shows different values. But if the switch on the screen it toggled, I want it to display a different set of values.

All the data is currently stored in an array I called `data`.

[Donut chart package I'm using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circular-chart)

I tried solving this problem with an if-statement to check if the toggle is enabled and changed the values of the `data` array accordingly. However, when I try this, I get the error `"data" is read-only` when I switch the toggle on.

See relevant code:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { Switch } from "react-native";
import { DonutChart } from "react-native-circular-chart";

const ResultScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const data = [
    { name: "Privacy", value: 30, color: "blue" },
    { name: "Integriteit", value: 20, color: "green" },
    { name: "Collegialiteit", value: 15, color: "pink" },
    { name: "Slaap", value: 35, color: "red" },
  ];

  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    if (isEnabled) {
      data = [
        { name: "Privacy", value: 30, color: "blue" },
        { name: "Integriteit", value: 20, color: "green" },
        { name: "Collegialiteit", value: 15, color: "pink" },
        { name: "Slaap", value: 35, color: "red" },
      ];
    } else {
      data = [
        { name: "Honor", value: 50, color: "blue" },
        { name: "Usage 2", value: 10, color: "green" },
        { name: "Usage 3", value: 10, color: "pink" },
        { name: "Usage 4", value: 30, color: "red" },
      ];
    }
    setIsEnabled((previousState) => !previousState);
  };
  return (
    <DonutChart
      data={data}
      strokeWidth={15}
      radius={100}
      containerWidth={500}
      containerHeight={500}
      type="butt"
      startAngle={0}
      endAngle={360}
      animationType="slide"
    />
  );
};

export default ResultScreen;
```

Feel free to reach out if you need any more context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here, the quickest one given your code would be to add ternary check in your data prop of the chart, so when you change the toggle state, it will display different data. It would look like this

```
 const enabledData = [
    { name: "Privacy", value: 30, color: "blue" },
    { name: "Integriteit", value: 20, color: "green" },
    { name: "Collegialiteit", value: 15, color: "pink" },
    { name: "Slaap", value: 35, color: "red" },
  ];

 const disabledData = [
    { name: "Honor", value: 50, color: "blue" },
    { name: "Usage 2", value: 10, color: "green" },
    { name: "Usage 3", value: 10, color: "pink" },
    { name: "Usage 4", value: 30, color: "red" },
  ];

  const toggleSwitch = () => {
   setIsEnabled(!isEnabled);
  };

  return (
   <DonutChart
     data={isEnabled ? enabledData : disabledData}
     strokeWidth={15}
     radius={100}
     containerWidth={500}
     containerHeight={500}
     type="butt"
     startAngle={0}
     endAngle={360}
     animationType="slide"
   />
 );
```

This should do the job for you, however I think you should look into optimising this logic/component if you are building something scalable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It did the job for now indeed. I'm very new to programming in general and this is the 1st react-native app I'm making but thank you for the suggestion to optimize this is in the future! I'd appreciate if I can contact you about that when and if the time comes :)

Comment: Glad it works! Feel free to contact me whenever you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a const try declaring it using let.
eg  let data = []

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Declaring it as let stopped the error but for some reason the data didn't switch when the toggle was enabled either.